# behaving NSUserDefaults as a two plist File?

Tags: iphone

In UserDefault file I have six fields. I want to persist two field always and reset four other field in some scenario. What is best approach to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your want the four field to reset with their default values.

And the default value may be an `empty string` ,

```
 #define KDefault @"" 
 NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 if (standardUserDefaults)
 {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:KDefault forKey:@"first"];
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:KDefault forKey:@"two"];
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:KDefault forKey:@"third"];
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:KDefault forKey:@"four"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
 }
```

**Edited:**
For removing field rather than resetting: Use the below

```
        [standardUserDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"first"];
        [standardUserDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"two"];
        [standardUserDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"third"];
        [standardUserDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"four"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: @jhaliya- thanks for reply is there any way to remove four field instead of reseting ???

Answer (score 0):

.you can use NSFileManager..sample code

```
    NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"user.plist"]; //3
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"user" ofType:@"plist"]; //5

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
}

NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
//load from savedStock example int value
NSString* userName;
NSString* password;
NSString* pin;
userName = [savedStock objectForKey:@"name"];
password = [savedStock objectForKey:@"password"];

if([userName isEqualToString:@"some"] && [userName isEqualToString:@"some"] && [pin isEqualToString:@"some"])
{
    [self setAdd];
}
else 
{
    [self pinAdd];
}
```